# JQuery UI Selectable(): Check if only one element is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

How can I check if only one element was selected when using JQuery UI's `selectable()`?
So if I just click on one element and select it, an alert box would show. But if I used the lasso to select multiple items, the alert box would not show.

```
$('#area').selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui)
    {
        //if number of selected elements=1:
        //do something

    }
);
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `length` property to check the number of items selected:

```
$('#area').selectable({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        if ($('.ui-selected').length === 1) {
             //only one selected
        }    
    }
);
```